# How can this for loop that loops this array be turned into a one liner?

Tags: java

do you guys know how to simplify or turn this code into a one liner and ignore the library
just the code itself

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i += 1) {
    inventory.SpellMenu.setItem(slots.get(i), (ItemStack) inventory.ItemQueue.toArray()[i]);
}
```

Comment: My Java is rusty but I believe that can be compressed to one line as is

Comment: you mean remove the spaces no like i meant use streams or other forms of simplification. Theres probs a way to do this with streams just don't know how

Comment: That I can't answer but you did ask how to turn the code into a one-liner. Remove the line breaks and it should still work as written. In general, you can take most multiline code and replace the line breaks with a semicolon to tell Java the statement is complete.

Comment: You can generally convert a `for` loop into Stream using something like `IntStream.rangeClose(0, 8).forEach(i -> /* whatever is done in the for loop */);` - but that is not really better (or is it, eventually?)

Comment: you just answered my question lol

Answer (score 0):

From what I already see, your code is one line inside for loop. For cleaner code, it is recommended that the maximum length of a line be 70-80 characters, so you can reformat the upcast into a variable to make it more readable.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i += 1) {
    ItemStack stack = (ItemStack) inventory.ItemQueue.toArray();
    inventory.SpellMenu.setItem(slots.get(i), stack[i]);
}
```

In for loop, I don't see any way to reduce code, but you can remove the parentheses in case you leave the code like was.

Comment: No, the `inventory.ItemQueue.toArray()` is not an ItemStack; it's an array. The ItemStack is `inventory.ItemQueue.toArray()[i]`.

Comment: it should be `ItemStack[] stack` instead of just ItemStack like what k314159 suggested

Answer (score -2):

use a `IntStream` and range from 1 to 8 and use a `foreach` to do what you want after

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 8).forEach(i -> inventory.SpellMenu.setItem(slots.get(i), (ItemStack) inventory.ItemQueue.toArray()[i]));
```

Comment: more efficient? how that? creating more objects and basically doing the same? (not to mention the "range from 1 ..." in contrast with `rangeClosed(0, ...`;  kind of seen that code before...)